# HTML check variable undefined with ngIf excluding case when value is 0

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am using Angular 2 and would like to check if a variable value is `undefined` using the htm `*ngIf` condition.

If I use `<span *ngIf="!testvar">`, it also covers the case when variable `testvar = 0`, but I would like to exclude the case when it is 0.

The following works, but those are 2 checks:

```
<span *ngIf="!testvar && testvarl != 0"></span>
```

I would like to check this case with only condition to shorten it and make it cleaner.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 55):

You can just write:

```
*ngIf="testvar !== undefined"
```

Answer (score 4):

And if you might be worried about **null** too:

```
*ngIf="testvar !== undefined && testvar !== null"
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `*ngIf="testvar != undefined"`

Comment: I believe this could also be `*ngIf="!!testvar"`

Comment: no because that will also kill the 0, because 0 is falsy and that is the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="!!foo">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</ng-template>
```

"Hello World" will be hidden if foo is the undefined or null or empty string and it will show Hello World if the foo is a number or boolean is true or string or array or object.

Comment: This will also be false if "foo" is number 0.
And [ngIf] should be *ngIf

Answer (score 0):

Despite, this is an old topic, this is a possible solution that can help others:

```
<span *ngIf="isValid(testvar)"></span>

isValid(str: String) {
    return typeof str !== 'undefined' && str != 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use functions in your template like that, for performance